# os.listdir using input from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, listdir

I am trying to read a line from a file and use the content as an argument for the os.listdir method

```
f = open('test.txt', "r+")
test = f.readlines()
contentlist = []
contentlist = os.listdir(test[0])
```

*which returns*

```
"WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'c:\\test\n\\*.*"
```

which makes sense because that's how test[0] is written in the array. But how do I get the "c:\test\" version out of that array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fetch files by glob patterns use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
contentlist = glob.glob(test[0])
```

Comment: Oh, actually solved the next step of my script aswell. Seems to be a pretty handy module, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
import glob
f = open('test.txt', "r+")
test = f.readlines()
contentlist = []
contentlist = glob.glob(test[0])
print contentlist
```